# Integrate $\int{ \frac{r}{(h^2 + r^2 - 2^{1/2}hr)^{1/2}} dr }$

Tags: integration

This integral comes from a physics book when calculating potential difference between vertex and center of cone. I'm not good at integration. Please help.

*update:*
[image]

This is the required answer.
The second integral is in ln form. I have reached there by using the required formula but equation inside ln is less by factor of $2$. What am i doing wrong?

Also how formula for ln is derived?

Comment: Consider including your progress in your question so that others may provide constructive feedback.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int{ \frac{r}{(h^2 + r^2 - 2^{1/2}hr)^{1/2}} dr }$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\int{ \frac{2r-\sqrt{2}h+\sqrt{2}h}{(h^2 + r^2 - \sqrt{2}hr)^{1/2}} dr }$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\int{ \frac{2r-\sqrt{2}h}{(h^2 + r^2 - \sqrt{2}hr)^{1/2}} dr }+\frac{1}{2}\int{ \frac{\sqrt{2}h}{(h^2 + r^2 - \sqrt{2}hr)^{1/2}} dr }$$
Try a $u$-substitution on the first one, and completing the square + trig-substitution on the 2nd. If you aren't familiar with these techniques, there are readily available references on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

Let me write your integral as  $$ \int \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-\sqrt{2}ax+a^2}}dx$$
Then first consider the change of variable  $u={x^2-\sqrt{2}ax+a^2} $, the  $du=(2x-\sqrt{2}a )dx$, thus the integral becomes: $$ \int \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-\sqrt{2}ax+a^2}}dx = \frac{1}{2} \int \frac{2x-\sqrt{2}a+\sqrt{2}a}{\sqrt{x^2-\sqrt{2}ax+a^2}}dx=$$ 
$$\frac{1}{2} \int \frac{2x-\sqrt{2}a}{\sqrt{x^2-\sqrt{2}ax+a^2}}dx  + \frac{1}{2} \int \frac{\sqrt{2}a}{\sqrt{x^2-\sqrt{2}ax+a^2}}dx  = $$
$$ \frac{1}{2} \int \frac{du}{\sqrt{u}} + \frac{a}{\sqrt{2}} \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-\sqrt{2}ax+a^2}}dx  $$
The first integral is simply $\sqrt{u}$, again to the initial variable,  the first integral is  $\sqrt{x^2-\sqrt{2}ax+a^2}$.

Now, consider the second inetgral, and use complete square in the denomenator $$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-\sqrt{2}ax+a^2}} =  \int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2-\sqrt{2}ax+ \frac{a^2}{2}+\frac{a^2}{2}}}=  \int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{(x-\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}})^2+ \frac{a^2}{2}}}= \int \frac{dx}{\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}\sqrt{\frac{2}{a^2}(x-\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}})^2+ 1}} =\frac{\sqrt{2}}{a}\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{a}x-1)^2+ 1}} $$
let $v= \frac{\sqrt{2}}{a}x-1$, then  $dv=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{a} dx $, and so this last integral can be written as  $$ \int \frac{dv}{\sqrt{v^2+1}}= arsinh(v) $$ thus your final integral is
$$ \int \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-\sqrt{2}ax+a^2}}dx=\sqrt{x^2-\sqrt{2}ax+a^2} +\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}} arcsinh\Big(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{a}x-1 \Big) +C$$

Comment: Please see the update.

Comment: @A.Z Note that  $arcsinh(x)=\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})$, then subsituting in the above form(the answer we get from the integration), you will get the desired answer(the answer you wrote in the update).